# gitignore on home to track changes to configuration

Tags: git

I wish to track the config files in my home directory. I have the following `gitignore` file:

```
*
!.*
*/
!.config/
*.zip
*~
.cache
.recently-used
.xsession-errors
.ICEauthority
.Xauthority
*log*
**/*cache*
**/*lock*
**/*pass*
**/*log
.bash_history
```

but I do not see any directory or file in `.config`. Why is that so? It excludes all directories and then un-ignores the `.config/`?

I expect then to add a line to keep only the `conf` files (I understand that these are not all the configureations, but this is a start)

Comment: maybe reconsider "configuration", why do you think `conf` files under `.config` directory? if you do have some conf files under .config, you should `git add` them at first then to track the files.

Comment: in linux most of the local configuration files are in directories under `.config`, e.g. in `.config/ario/options.xml`. The shown `.gitignore` file does not include the subdirectories of `.config` except those that start with `.`